# use value from input field in html dialog box to var in code.gs using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dialog

I have a dialog box where user can select a year. Then I want the server to process the selected value in the function doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear).

Looked at several discussions, but can't get it working. Looks like I need to do something with .withSuccesHandler().

Code.gs

```
function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DropDown_NewCompetitionFile');
  thisYear = new Date();
  htmlDlg.thisYear = thisYear.getFullYear();
  htmlDlg.nextYear = htmlDlg.thisYear + 1;

  htmlDlg = htmlDlg.evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Make selection');
};

function doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(theYear);  
}
```

HTML doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

Year
<select name="Competition_year" id="Competition_year" type="integer">
  <option value=<?= thisYear?>><?= thisYear?></option>
  <option value="nextYear"><?= nextYear?></option>
</select>

<hr/>

<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Submit</button>

<script>
  var theYear = document.getElementById("Competition_year").value;   
  google.script.run.doSomethingWithCompetitionYear();
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple boiler plate for doing something with .withSuccessHandler**

I added some JQuery, a msgdiv, withSuccessHandler() and a doSomethingWithCompetitionYear() server function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

Year
<select name="Competition_year" id="Competition_year" type="integer">
  <option value=<?= thisYear?>><?= thisYear?></option>
  <option value="nextYear"><?= nextYear?></option>
</select>

<hr/>

<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Submit</button>
<div id="msgdiv"></div>
<script>
  var theYear = document.getElementById("Competition_year").value;   
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
     document.getElementById("msgdiv").innerHTML=msg;
  }))
  .doSomethingWithCompetitionYear();
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close({year:$("#competition_year").val()});
  };
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs:

```
function doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(obj) {
  return Utilities.formatString('I did something with this year: %s',obj.year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Situation:

If I understand you correctly you have a dialog box with two options, and you want to pass information on the selected option (in this case, `2020` or `2021`) to the server-side function `doSomethingWithCompetitionYear();` when the `Submit` button is clicked.

#### Issues:

If that's the case, you don't actually need a success handler. You just need to pass the selected value as a parameter of `doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear);`.

Also, if you want this to happen when the `Submit` button is clicked. You should add this to the `closeDia` function. Otherwise, `doSomethingWithCompetitionYear();` will run before submission.

Finally, if you want to pass the next year (`2021`), and not the string "nextYear", you'll have to use [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) on the element's value.

#### Modification 1. Next year value:

Replace this:

```html
<option value="nextYear"><?= nextYear?></option>
```

For this:

```html
<option value=<?= nextYear?>><?= nextYear?></option>
```

#### Modification 2. Calling server-side function when button is clicked:

Replace this:

```html
<script>
  var theYear = document.getElementById("Competition_year").value;   
  google.script.run.doSomethingWithCompetitionYear();
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

For this:

```html
<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    var theYear = document.getElementById("Competition_year").value;   
    google.script.run.doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear); // theYear parameter has to be passed to server-side function
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use information coming from `doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear);` in the client-side, you should use a success handler, which can call a client-side function that will get this data as a parameter (the server-side function, called by `google.script.run` doesn't return anything by itself, it needs a callback function). It would be something like this:

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yourClientSideFunction).doSomethingWithCompetitionYear(theYear);
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)